# Online Storage that I can mount on my mac

Tags: storage

Not sure if this is possible, but I would like to set up one of my RaspPi's as online storage. That I can access over the internet but I would like to be able to mount it as a drive on my mac when I use it. Not have to use a web UI

Is this possible and if so can someone point me in the direction of some set up instructions.

Comment: I don't understand why you can say hi and thanks. Does it take up so much space?

Comment: Ashley, see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you could set this up.  You could use a whole host of software to mount the RPi's storage as an ftp or sftp drive, you could use [OwnCloud](https://owncloud.org/), [btsync](https://www.getsync.com/), or a zillion other things that you could find by googling.

Comment: Thanks WebDAV seam to be what I need to look for. Which OwnCloud does have.

Answer (score 4):

If you install `netatalk` on the Pi you can use it from OS X. 
You can connect using `open afp://raspberrypi.local` on the Mac. It is also possible to connect from the sidebar in `Finder` although I find this annoying.

This lets you access the shared items in `Finder` or any other file utility.

There is some configuration on the Pi (which you can find in the `man` if you install `netatalk`), but by default it mounts your home directory.

If you try this and have questions search this site for `netatalk` or ask in detail.