# Transfer a file from Raspberry to Mac

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, data-transfer, jessie-lite

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 with Jessie Lite (terminal only) and I have to transfer a file which is on my Raspberry to a Mac.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run the command on your Mac:

```
scp pi@raspberry.local:/path/to/file .
```

And the file will be transferred to your current directory.

Assuming your Raspberry Pi is accessible through its default hostname `raspberry.local` in the local network. Also assuming the user `pi` has read access to the file.

Answer (score 3):

[Techraf's answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/59180/34558) is good, and what I would do myself. However it won't work if SSH is not enabled. Here are a couple of other alternatives. You could use a service like Dropbox. or what used to be called sneaker net, and copy the file to a flashdrive, you could even copy the file to the `/boot` partition of your Pi's SD card (the boot partiton is readable from macOS and Windows).

Dropbox has support for the commandline. Installation and usage details can be found [here](http://www.dropboxwiki.com/tips-and-tricks/using-the-official-dropbox-command-line-interface-cli).

To copy the file to the SD card or a flash drive you will need either the `cp` (copy command) or the `mv` (move command) you can read the manual (help) page for these commands by using the `man` command: `man mv` or `man cp`. You may also want to read the man page for the man command usng `man man`.

Comment: Does dropbox run on ARM now?

Comment: @goldilocks https://www.raspberrypi.org/magpi/dropbox-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score 2):

There are **many** ways to do this. `ssh` certainly works from the command line, but there are better ways, which most macOS users would find familiar.

If you install `netatalk` on the Pi you can use it from OS X. You can connect using
`open afp://raspberrypi.local` on the Mac. It is also possible to connect from the sidebar in Finder although I find this annoying.

See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/39665/8697

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you have to configure a **samba server**, this is a practical guide [RaspberryWebServer](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html) to install and configure it. With it, you can access on your raspberry from every device.

Answer (score 0):

You can install cyberduck https://cyberduck.io/download/
and use graphical interface for connecting and copying files from your rapsberry pi through to your mac

Only important part is you have to select sftp instead of ftp connection

[image: cyberduck raspberry pi setup]

Comment: Isn't this require an SFTP server installation on the Raspberry Pi? And there is an accepted answer that uses scp.

Comment: If you enable ssh you also enable sftp server (and you don't have to install it https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/sftp.md) . Using cyberduck is just another solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For one-off transfers from your Pi you could run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` in the directory where your file is located and then, on your Mac, browse to http://raspberrypi.local:8000/ to download it. A caveat to this is if the file is an image or HTML the you might need to use something like 'Save As...' or 'Download source' to download and not display it. Type Ctrl+C on the Pi to close the python web server when you're done.

For a more permanent solution then use one of the other fine answers already provided.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html